# CSS Media Queries: using comparisons

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

I'd like to try to work out a method of adaptive webpage design to coexist with both mobile and desktop browsers.

At first it looked like using Media Queries in CSS was what I needed, so I went with that, but it looks like Google Chrome is messing up what I wanted to do.

Compared to most browsers, for the most part only mobile browsers respond to the orientation media query, which seemed to be a good way to target a mobile browser, no matter the screen size.  However, for some reason, Google Chrome not only responds to this, but will actually select Landscape and Portrait depending on the dimensions of the viewport (the window itself) and has nothing to do with the position of the screen itself.

This brought me to another potential idea.  I noticed that on my mobile devices, device-width and device-height will swap positions depending on landscape and portrait modes, while Google Chrome on a desktop always reports the monitor's proper dimensions, even when Chrome thinks the window size qualifies as Portrait mode.
What I'm hoping to do is figure out a way to make a media query that determines if the device-width is greater than device-height.  This should allow me to determine the true orientation of the screen, regardless of viewport size and Chrome's orientation value.

My eventual goal is to be able to design a page with a specifically mobile-friendly layout for any device that reports Orientation: Portrait AND the Device-Width is less than Device-Height, which should only ever happen on a true mobile device in portrait mode (or the rare sideways PC monitor, which I don't mind accidently targetting), while serving a landscape/desktop friendly layout to any device with a screen that is wider than it is tall.

I am adamantly avoiding using any form of Javascript, useragent query, or server-side scripting to accomplish this. Media Queries seem to be the fastest and least costly (processing wise) method to have a page that actively shapes itself to the current device and will also shift its position in real-time as the mobile device rotates between orientations.

My ultimate question for this post is: Can I specify some form of expression in a media query in CSS that will simply compare the Device-Width and Device-Height and display one style when the width is greater than height, and vice versa?

Something like:

@media screen and (device-width > device-height) //true landscape mode

@media screen not (device-width > device-height) //true portrait mode or square screen

Comment: You can use `and (orientation: landscape)` or `and (orientation: portrait)` Read more here: [Media queries for standard devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, this does not work when factoring in Google Chrome on desktop systems.  Chrome will report "orientation: portrait" when the viewport is taller than it is wide, falsely suggesting that the screen itself has been rotated.  My goal is to strictly target a mobile device in portrait mode and to ignore Google Chrome (desktop) when it incorrectly reports a portrait orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tweaking and testing, I came up with the following combination of media queries that seem to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

***@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) and (min-device-aspect-ratio: 1/1)***
//This targets any screen that is in true Landscape orientation, including desktop browsers.  This should also target square screens where the browser reports landscape orientation.

***@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-device-aspect-ratio: 1/1)***
//This targets strictly desktop browsers that have a window resized into what the browser considers "portrait" mode.  This works in Chrome, Firefox, and MS Edge (haven't tested others).  More specifically, this targets any browser that reports portrait mode, but where the screen is actually in landscape position.  This may also target square screens where the browser reports portrait orientation.

***@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) and (max-device-aspect-ratio: 1/1)***
//This strictly targets devices that are actually in portrait orientation, mainly mobile devices (although it may target desktops with rotated monitors)
*This may also target square screens reported to be in portrait mode, so you may need an additional query that targets exactly square screens.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy that you got the way to do what you where looking for, but I think readers should take in account a couple of things:

First, as you said, Monitors can also rotate, in fact is very common in offices to see that kind of monitors.

Second, **in mobile you can also have a Landscape viewport in Portrait orientation** or viceversa, as you can split the screen in two.

Third, devices such as the **Pixel 2XL and iPhone X** have a proportion of 18:9 and 19.5:9 respectively, which means that **half screen will return Landscape**.

Finally, what really matters is the viewport orientation because is what determines the content area, whether is a desktop or a mobile screen. If you resize your desktop window you should also thing about doing some responsive to optimise your available space.

As bonus, **in iPhone** width referes to viewport while device-width refers to **the screen width, which, unlike Android, is always the larger side of the screen**.

I'd love to have an easy answer to your question, but there is not. Doing responsive is not easy. Maybe [this article](http://www.elcssar.com/responsive/media-queries-breakpoints) ([EN](https://translate.google.es/translate?sl=es&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elcssar.com%2Fresponsive%2Fmedia-queries-breakpoints)) can help you. It gives some clues to split between Desktop vs Laptop, Laptop vs Tablet and Tablet vs Mobile.